# Variable String.Format length

Tags: c#, string, format

I have the following code:

```
var str = "ABC";
var n = 7;
var output = String.Format("{0,n}", str);
```

This should output the string

```
"    ABC"
```

How should I change the line above?

Comment: How do `str.Length` and `n` relate? Is `n` supposed to represent the value of `str.Length`?

Comment: Sorry I made some mistake in the code above and fixed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Format strings are just strings too - you can define the format separately:

```
int n = 3;
string format = string.Format("{{0,{0}}}", n);
//or more readable: string format = "{0," + n + "}";
var output = string.Format(format, str);
```

Edit:

After your update it looks like what you want can also be achieved by [`PadLeft()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx):

```
var str = "ABC";
string output = str.PadLeft(7);
```

Comment: Maybe I cannot use the PadLeft since the string is not always constant (above was just an example), but I forgot about that function too. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just write:

```
var lineLength = String.Format("{0," + n + "}", str);
```

Comment: More readable than the accepted answer (and uses fewer lines)

Answer (score 2):

```
var s="Hello my friend";
string leftSpace = s.PadLeft(20,' '); //pad left with special character
string rightSpace = s.PadRight(20,' '); //pad right with special character
```