# How to increase/decrease date character spacing in C#

Tags: c#

[image: Date Character Spacing]

How do I increase/Decrease space between date characters.

D -- > -- > D  /  M -- > M /  Y --> Y--> Y -- Y-->

should look like:

```
0    8      0    8     2   0   1  6
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @SteveWellens I want to print on a form and make sure it's printed on date boxes.

Comment: Can you say what's your actual requirement? It seems to be [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Do learn about printing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it looks like you are looking for output formatter

String.format can be used in this case:

```
var someDate = new System.DateTime(2016, 8, 8);

string.Format("{0,10}:{1,20}:{2,30}", someDate.Month, someDate.Day, someDate.Year)
```

Output:

```
  "         8:                   8:                          2016"
```

You can put any value {0,XX} depending on how much padding you want for a given parameter.

Moreover check out [date and time formatters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: this works, how can I control this padding via textbox?

Comment: Possible...check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542994/variable-string-format-length

Answer (score 2):

Something like this good enough?

```
var padded = string.Join(" ", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy").ToCharArray())
```

Output:

`0  8     0  8     2  0  1  6`

Here's another option:

```
public class CharWithPadding
{
    public char Char;
    public int Padding;
}
```

...

```
//Populate a list with the current date, and default padding
var paddingDictionary = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy")
    .ToCharArray()
    .Select(c => new CharWithPadding { Char = c, Padding = 2 })
    .ToList();

//Add extra padding to specific point in the date-string
paddingDictionary[2].Padding = 10;

var output = string.Join("", paddingDictionary.Select(cwp => cwp.Char + new string(' ', cwp.Padding)));
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use that with a fixed space font so the spacing is consistent (like Courier).   However, I'm going to guess it will be easier to break the date into 8 characters and print each one separately.

Comment: this is a good answer dave bish, I have tried this and it works, for this I'm giving you vote-up. 

but problem is I have multiple forms and their date boxes is of different sizes. 

sometimes 08/08/201 prints correctly but 6 is either too away from the box or too near, in this scenario I get stucked with this option. 

if I can individually space each character that's the best thing.

Comment: @SteveWellens I originally had this idea, either I break them into each one seperately or use the answer provided by sanjay sutar with a spacing controlled by numeric up down or textboxes.

Comment: Added another option

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is either called [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), or more likely [letter spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter-spacing). However, if you know exact locations on the form you're printing to, you're probably much better off creating and positioning separate elements from the pieces of the `DateTime` object, rather than trying to tweak the spacing:

```
DateTime FormDate = DateTime.Now;
Box1.Text = FormDate.DayToString();
Box2.Text = FormDate.Month.ToString();
```

etc.

Many fonts have different widths of each character, including the ' '; sometimes even different spaces between letter combinations. If the font (or the form) ever changes or if this code is ever re-used, life will be much easier if your solution isn't font-dependent.

Comment: I see, to be more precise, I want independent spacing of each character.